# GoogleSignIn iOS: preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation (7) crash

Tags: ios, google-signin

We're experiencing [this crash](http://crashes.to/s/4928e13796f) from the GoogleSignIn iOS framework v4.0.1 (linked via CocoaPods).

`Fatal Exception: UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation
preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation '(7)' must match a supported interface orientation: 'portrait, landscapeLeft, landscapeRight, portraitUpsideDown'!`

```
Fatal Exception: UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation
0  CoreFoundation                 0x184656fe0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1830b8538 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x184656f28 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  UIKit                          0x18a87cbbc -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentationInWindow:fromInterfaceOrientation:]
4  UIKit                          0x18b159cf0 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _adjustOrientationIfNecessaryInWindow:forViewController:preservingViewController:]
5  UIKit                          0x18aad6d3c -[UIPresentationController _dismissWithAnimationController:interactionController:target:didEndSelector:]
6  UIKit                          0x18aafd53c -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithAnimationController:interactionController:completion:]
7  UIKit                          0x18a8b2848 -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:]
8  UIKit                          0x18a85a6dc -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:]
9  UIKit                          0x18a85a4bc -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:]
10 UIKit                          0x18aafc7e4 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:]
11 UIKit                          0x18a85a230 -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:]
12 Remind101                      0x10069f6a0 -[GIDSignIn dismissViewController:]
13 Remind101                      0x100699c4c -[GIDSignIn handleURL:fromGoogleSSOApp:]
14 Remind101                      0x100699b60 -[GIDSignIn handleURL:sourceApplication:annotation:]
15 Remind101                      0x1001a7398 -[RDAppDelegate application:openURL:options:] (RDAppDelegate.m:495)
16 UIKit                          0x18aa13c28 __45-[UIApplication _applicationOpenURL:payload:]_block_invoke
17 UIKit                          0x18aa136b0 -[UIApplication _applicationOpenURL:payload:]
18 SafariServices                 0x19307a628 -[SFSafariViewController remoteViewController:hostApplicationOpenURL:]
19 SafariServices                 0x193072038 -[SFBrowserRemoteViewController willOpenURLInHostApplication:]
20 CoreFoundation                 0x18465ce80 __invoking___
21 CoreFoundation                 0x1845522c4 -[NSInvocation invoke]
22 FrontBoardServices             0x186200884 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
23 FrontBoardServices             0x1862006f0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext]
24 FrontBoardServices             0x186200aa0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]
25 CoreFoundation                 0x18460542c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
26 CoreFoundation                 0x184604d9c __CFRunLoopDoSources0
27 CoreFoundation                 0x1846029a8 __CFRunLoopRun
28 CoreFoundation                 0x184532da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
29 GraphicsServices               0x185f9d074 GSEventRunModal
30 UIKit                          0x18a7edc9c UIApplicationMain
31 Remind101                      0x10015b958 main (main.m:16)
32 libdyld.dylib                  0x18354159c start
```

Our app delegate method (frame 15 in the stack trace) is implemented as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
    NSString *sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey];
    NSString *annotation = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey];

    // ... bunch of app-specific checks

    return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

And our crash logging shows the url being opened looks like this (obfuscated because I don't know if the numbers or uids are identifiable in any way):

```
openURL:com.googleusercontent.apps.(number)-(uid):/oauth2callback?code=4/-(uid)# sourceApplication:com.apple.SafariViewService annotation:(null)
```

We've received nearly 300 of these crashes in the last 7 days. Crashes began August 14th (spiking on the 17th) and are appearing on versions that were released prior to that date, so I don't believe it's anything we introduced via our app. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What iOS version are these crashes happening on?

Comment: @brandonscript All that we support currently - 9, 10, 11. Primary on iOS 10 as that's where the vast majority of our users are, naturally.

Comment: Has there been an iOS update recently that touched all those versions? Can you reproduce on iOS 11?

Answer (score 1):

From the stack trace the crash happens after GoogleSignIn dismisses the SFSafariViewerController. The previous UIViewController (not part of GoogleSignIn) is exposed again, but it returns an unrecognized value (7) for preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation. Note that if that UIViewController is your first screen, its preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation may not be called in its initial appearance, but the UISupportedInterfaceOrientations values in your plist are used instead. So you could have been returning the incorrect UIInterfaceOrientation from your UIViewController without knowing it, until the view appears again after user signs in with Google, causing the crash.

Comment: I have to respectfully disagree. Not with what the crash is, I can of course read and interpret the error message, but I don't agree with your conclusion that it must be one of our view controllers. As noted in the question, these crashes started appearing on a certain date, and the crashes are affecting releases from before that date, so to me that indicates that it's not a change that we introduced causing this. To me it's equally likely the view controller being dismissed from the Google SSO App is not configured properly.

Comment: Furthermore, we don't override the preferredInterfaceOrientation method in our application - the values are defined in our app's plist using the supplied valid enum values.